# 「あまもり」と一段動詞「もれる」

Tags: verbs, renyōkei, godan-verbs, ichidan-verbs

天井などに欠陥があって，あめがふったときなどに，みずがもれだしてくることは「あまもり」といいます．しかし，この語の後半「もり」と関係があるとおもわれる動詞「もれる」は一段活用です．その連用形を名詞としてもちいているのだとすれば「もれ」でなくてはなりません．このことから，かつては，「もれる」とおなじ意味の「もる」という五段動詞があったのではないかとおもいたくなります．本当にそのような動詞があったのでしょうか？ (個人的には，高齢者が「もれる」という動詞を五段活用にしてつかっていても不思議ではないとおもいますが，実際にそのような例をきいたことがあるかどうかはわかりません．)

ちなみに，このサイトには，(「もれる」という動詞を例にすれば) 「『もれる』という動詞にはかつては『もる』という形もあった」というような主張が多々みられます．このような主張は，一段動詞がかつては二段動詞であったという当然の言明なのか，あるいは (上でのべたように) 当該一段動詞がかつては五段でも活用していたという言明なのか，はっきりしないこともあります．もし後者のような主張が「もれる」に対してなりたつならば，そのむねがはっきりわかるような資料などをしめしてくださるとありがたいです．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「漏る」という動詞は、現代語として存在します。

> [**も・る【漏る／×洩る】**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220503/meaning/m0u/)
>
> ［動ラ五（四）］
> **１** 「漏れる1」に同じ。「雨が―・る」
>
> **も・れる【漏れる／×洩れる】**
>
> **１** 液体・気体・光などがすきまから外へ出る。「ガスが―・れる」「声が―・れる」

なお、辞書には他にも定義が書いてありますが、個人的な経験では「雨漏り」のように、人間に由来しない自然物が、（通常、人間の意図に沿わない形で）漏れ出てくるような場面でしか聞いたことはありません。

BCCWJより若干の例文です。

> 百均で買ったマグカップだって、水が**漏る**わけじゃない。
> 隙**洩る**風に取り廻した張交屛風、湯の沸っている瀬戸の大火鉢
> やがて**漏る**であろう屋根とか、やがて枯れるであろう木とか。 *(["for the roof that will leak; for the tree that will fall."](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200331.txt))*